# Uncaught TypeError: state.weekday is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks

Following is my js file which is setting two times, starting time and ending times saving them in startTime useState and endTime useState. The thing is that now i want to use the add button to add more time slots in a single day. For that I made my startTime obj of keys and values as arrays. As i press the add button i want to add more time slots in the appendable arrays in setStartTime and setEndTime(yet to do). Following is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns"; // choose your lib
import { TimePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import CheckBox from "./CheckBox";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import RemoveIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Remove";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";

import "../compStyles/SetTime.css";
import { indexOf, times } from "lodash";

function Doctor() {
  
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState({
    Monday: [null],
    Tuesday: [null],
    Wednesday: [null],
    Thursday: [null],
    Friday: [null],
    Saturday: [null],
    Sunday: [null],
  });

  const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState({
    Monday: null,
    Tuesday: null,
    Wednesday: null,
    Thursday: null,
    Friday: null,
    Saturday: null,
    Sunday: null,
  });

  const handleAddFields = (i) => {
    setStartTime([...startTime, { Monday: null }]);
    console.log(i);
  };


  const handleTimeChange = (weekday, startEnd, time, index) => {
    

    switch (startEnd) {
      case "start":
        setStartTime(state => ({
          ...state,
          weekday:[...state.weekday, [index]:time]
        }))
        console.log("GODDAMN",startTime[weekday[index]]);
        break;
      case "end":
        setEndTime({ ...endTime, [weekday]: time });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  let items = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday",
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li>
              <CheckBox /> <h1>{item}</h1>{" "}
              {startTime[item].map((i) => {
                return (
                  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    <TimePicker
                      className="timepicker1"
                      value={startTime[item[indexOf(i)]]}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        handleTimeChange(item, "start", event, indexOf(i))
                      }
                    />
                    <h1>-</h1>
                    <TimePicker
                      value={endTime[item]}
                      onChange={(event) => handleTimeChange(item, "end", event)}
                    />
                  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                );
              })}
              <div className="icons">
                <IconButton>
                  <RemoveIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton onClick={(item) => handleAddFields(item)}>
                  <AddIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Doctor;
```

This image is before i set the starting time :
[main UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWIwP.png)

[When i set the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGcjK.png)

Comment: Why are you creating an array with a null in it. That's very weird and makes me suspect you are confused about how arrays work in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state.weekday` isn't iterable because it's undefined. `state.weekday` gets the value of the property with the name `weekday` on the object `state`. `state[weekday]` gets the value of the property whose name is the value of the variable weekday. In this case you want the later. Also note that you probably want

`[weekday]: [...`
Not
`weekday: [...`

Remember brackets if you want the object to behave like a map, periods if you want it to behave like an object.

Comment: Yes my bad I forgot to send the updated code.. It worked after this! Thank you